# I want to get data by the current URL, so I have set a post value, but it is set for all pages

Tags: magento2, url

I want to get data by the current URL, so I have set a post value. But it is set for all pages, and I want to unset it if another URL opens. How can I do it?

Please see my code:

```
if ($currenturl = 'https://example.com/delhi.html') {
    $this->request->setPostValue('location', '289');
}
```

Comment: How can a question based on a typo or lack of basic understanding of PHP get two upvotes? (also counts for the answers b.t.w.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `currenturl = 'https://example.com/delhi.html'` you are setting currenturl to that string which is why it triggers for all pages as you are returning true for that if statement.

What Key Shang said *should* work however when comparing strings you should use `===` instead of `==` as `==` is ambiguous and could return unexpected results.

So the result should be

```
if ($currenturl === "https://example.com/delhi.html") {
      $this->request->setPostValue('location','289');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to change `=` to  `==`, like below

```
if (currenturl == "https://example.com/delhi.html") {
      $this->request->setPostValue('location','289');
}
```